# Wait for async initialisation of a service?

Tags: typescript, async-await, nestjs

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  ...
  constructor(@Inject('CONFIG') private config:ConfigOptions){
    this.connection= // await initConnection(config); <-- this returns a promise! How to await this?
  }
   
  send(payload:string){
    this.connection.send(payload)
  }
}
```

How to `await` the async call to `initConnection()` to ensure the service is initialised before being used?

Comment: Instead of instantiating with `new`, create an asynchronous factory function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constructors cannot have asynchronous code, that's just how JavaScript is. What you can do instead is either make use of the `onModuleInit` hook and await the connection there, or take the `CONFIG` provider you have and make a `CONNECTION` provider via [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) with `useFactory` which can have an `await`. Something like

```js
{
  provide: 'CONNECTION',
  inject: ['CONFIG'],
  useFactory: async (config: ConfigOptions) => {
    return await initConnection(config);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome hint `onModuleInit` is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks!